# Instrumented Worklight 6.1.0.1 hybrid app crashes on recording start with MTWW 8.5.1.2

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

Worklight v6.1.0.1

MTWW v8.5.1.2

I'm able to record tests for the App on both Android emulator and Android Device successfully.

However the instrumented app crashes on both iOS simulator and iOS device. Tried with different versions of iOS, there is no change in this behavior. On hitting the record button for the app, the splash screen is shown and then immediately the app crashes.

We tried with iOS 6, 6.1, 7.0 on simulators and devices. In the Device console I get "Handler error" and the next line is "App terminated".

I'm able to record tests for the same app when instrumented using IBM Worklight 6.0

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with MTWW 8.5.1.2 and Worklight v 6.1.0.1 that could be the one you are describing.

In order to be sure, if you use the 6.0 or 6.1 simulator, could you type the following command line before launching the recording ?

**tail -f /var/log/system.log**

Then launch a recording, and copy/paste the terminal log please.

A testfix has already been produced and a hotfix for this issue will be released.

Answer (score 0):

An APAR has been created for this issue, APAR PI20298. (For worklight version 6.1 and workbench version 8.5.1.2) But IBM has informed that this issue cannot be fixed in test workbench 8.5.1.2 but has been fixed in 8.5.1.3, but validation on 8.5.1.3 is still in progress.

I hope this helps.